# Firefox 57.0 font is weird compared to Google Chrome font in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, fonts

[image: firefox font problem screenshot]

I already tried these:

1. Enabling and disabling hardware acceleration.
2. sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer culmus
3. Unity Tweak Tool >Font> Hinting > Slight
4. Changing the default fonts
5. Checking :Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above
6. sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts(it gives output:selecting 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' instead of 'msttcorefonts')

This is the google chrome screenshot:

[image: Google chrome Font looks much better]

Also , in about:config > gfx.font .There is no option for gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode which was given a solution 
[here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115938)

Comment: Have you checked in `about:preferences` and in **Language and Appearance** and in **Advanced** settings and checked that `Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above` is selected?

Comment: @Terrance Yes It was already checked.

Comment: Probably because you don't have the **core fonts** installed or maybe I'm wrong. Could you try the command `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts` and re-open the **FireFox** and try.

Comment: @AzkerM on running the command I got this:
Note, selecting 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' instead of 'msttcorefonts'
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.

Comment: Is your issue that DIFFERENT fonts are being used in Firefox web pages compared to Chrome?  For example, is Firefox using DejaVu, while chrome is using Arial?  Or, is your issue that the font HINTING is not as nice in Firefox, compared to Chrome.  For example, do fonts look fuzzy to you in Firefox but they look sharp in Chrome?

Comment: @PJSingh Yeah fonts in firefox looks much fuzzy than in chrome.Also, the problem is not in Windows Firefox though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Optional**

If it exists, remove `fonts.conf`; `fonts.conf` is used by KDE applications, but Ubuntu uses `gsettings` instead. On Ubuntu, it is a good idea to remove this file, so it does not interfere with your font settings. In a terminal, execute the following.

```
rm ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
```

**Select Hinting**

Select one of the following options, depending on your font hinting preference.

1. **Full Hinting** (*Try this first, since I suspect it is what you will like most*)

   If you want full hinting, execute the following in a terminal.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-*.conf
   sudo ln -sv /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-full.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
   ```
2. **Medium Hinting**

   If you want medium hinting, execute the following in a terminal.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-*.conf
   sudo ln -sv /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-medium.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
   ```
3. **Slight Hinting**

   To undo this change, or to use slight hinting (default), execute the following in a terminal.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-*.conf
   sudo ln -sv /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
   ```

**Check Results**

Reboot, since the above changes are global to your system.  Launch Firefox and hopefully you will see sharper, clearer fonts.  Also, note that the address / search bar in Firefox may still display slightly fuzzy fonts, and I have not found a way to change this.  However, you should see a marked improvement in web pages.

Comment: This doesn't change anything with Firefox 64 and Ubuntu 18.04. Also there is no `~/.config/fontconfig` so nothing to delete in the first (optional) step.